# Summing by string names Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I'm working with a data frame like this, but bigger and with more zone. I am trying to sum the `value` of the rows by their names. The total sum of the R or C zones goes in `total` column while the total sum of either M zones goes in `total1` .

Input:

`total`, `total1` are the desired output.

```
ID  Zone1   CHC1    Value1  Zone2     CHC2  Value2  Zone3   CHC3    Value3  total   total1
 1  R5B     100      10       C2        0     20      R10A   2       5        35       0
 1  C2       95      20      M2-6       5      6      R5B    7       3        23       6       
 3  C2       40      4        C4       60      6       0     6       0        10       0
 3  C1       100     8         0        0      0       0    100      0        8        0
 5  M1-5     10      6       M2-6      86     15       0     0       0        0        21
```

Comment: Look out for the possibilities of 'groupby': https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Is the "minimal output" the correct output desired?

Comment: Yes that's the correct output desired.

Comment: @Zesima29 why you don't have the row  with ID = 3 in your output?

Comment: @Ben.T because I didn't perform any operation over them. ID = 3 would have a total of 0 in both total columns because I didn't set a statement to do any sum on them. `('R2')` only sums when R2 is found and `('C1|C4')` sums when both of them are in the row.

Comment: Can `R2`, `C1`, `C4` appear multiple times in single row or they appear at most once?

Comment: @gyoza they can appear only once per row, but there are other values with alike names like c4_1, R2A that i would like to skip.

Comment: @Zesima29 Your question is still unclear, Can you try to elaborate more and give a clear and concise stmt what are the actions you are trying to do and what is the expected result.

Comment: @min2bro I just want to sum the values according to its zone for example I type this `name.df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('C2', 'C3',)]]`  I want to go over all the rows summing the values `'C2' or 'C3'` that it may encounter.

Comment: @Zesima29 which values needs to sum up, there are multiple values in your dataset, is it value 1 or value 2 or value 3, from the output it looks like you are summing value 1 and value 3

Comment: @min2bro I wrote a better example,but  I'm summing whatever value is beside the zone that I'm stating on the str.contains method.

Comment: @Zesima29 Still their are ambiguities in your questions and examples. Try to think from a new user to make him understand, and Reframe your Question.

Comment: @ScottBoston I made the question clearer the output is in the total, total1 column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for DataFrames for `Zones` and `Values`:

```
z = df.filter(like='Zone')
v = df.filter(like='Value')
```

Then create `boolean DataFrame`s by [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `apply` if want check substrings:

```
m1 = z.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('R|C'))
m2 = z.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('M'))

#for check strings
#m1 = z == 'R2'
#m2 = z.isin(['C1', 'C4'])
```

---

Last filter by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)  `v` and `sum` per rows:

```
df['t'] = v.where(m1.values).sum(axis=1).astype(int)
df['t1'] = v.where(m2.values).sum(axis=1).astype(int)

print (df)
   ID Zone1  CHC1  Value1 Zone2  CHC2  Value2 Zone3  CHC3  Value3   t  t1
0   1   R5B   100      10    C2     0      20  R10A     2       5  35   0
1   1    C2    95      20  M2-6     5       6   R5B     7       3  23   6
2   3    C2    40       4    C4    60       6     0     6       0  10   0
3   3    C1   100       8     0     0       0     0   100       0   8   0
4   5  M1-5    10       6  M2-6    86      15     0     0       0   0  21
```

Comment: How do you deal with the case where both `C1` AND `C4` need to be present in 1 row?

Comment: @gyoza - Need `m2 = (z == 'C1') & (z == 'C2')`

Comment: That causes all `False` in the mask since one cell cannot take 2 values at the same time

Comment: @gyoza - Yes, I agrre, AND have no sense here.

Answer (score 1):

Solution1 (simpler code but slower and less flexible)

```
total = []
total1 = []

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    temp = df.iloc[i].tolist()
    if "R2" in temp:
        total.append(temp[temp.index("R2")+1])
    else:
        total.append(0)
    if ("C1" in temp) & ("C4" in temp):
        total1.append(temp[temp.index("C1")+1] + temp[temp.index("C4")+1])
    else:
        total1.append(0)

df["Total"] = total
df["Total1"] = total1
```

Solution2 (faster than solution1 and easier to customize but possibly memory intensive)

```
# columns to use
cols = df.columns.tolist()
zones = [x for x in cols if x.startswith('Zone')]
vals = [x for x in cols if x.startswith('Value')]

# you can customize here
bucket1 = ['R2']
bucket2 = ['C1', 'C4']
thresh = 2 # "OR": 1, "AND": 2

original = df.copy()

# bucket1 check
for zone in zones:
    df.loc[~df[zone].isin(bucket1), cols[cols.index(zone)+1]] = 0

original['Total'] = df[vals].sum(axis=1)
df = original.copy()

# bucket2 check
for zone in zones:
    df.loc[~df[zone].isin(bucket2), cols[cols.index(zone)+1]] = 0

df['Check_Bucket'] = df[zones].stack().reset_index().groupby('level_0')[0].apply(list)
df['Check_Bucket'] = df['Check_Bucket'].apply(lambda x: len([y for y in x if y in bucket2]))
df['Total1'] = df[vals].sum(axis=1)
df.loc[df.Check_Bucket < thresh, 'Total1'] = 0
df.drop('Check_Bucket', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

When I expanded original dataframe to 100k rows, solution 1 took `11.4 s ± 82.1 ms per loop`, while solution 2 took `3.53 s ± 29.8 ms per loop`. The difference is because solution 2 does not for-looping over row direction.

Comment: iterrows should be the last resort for any solution, it might impact the performance.

Comment: @ min2bro Thanks, I replaced iterrows() with simple looping. iterrows() takes 796 µs ± 950 ns per loop, while simple looping takes 541 µs ± 7.02 µs per loop with my PC.

Comment: @gyoza Thanks I appreciate your effort. The problem with this answer is that I need to add too many if statements and let’s say I change the `&` statement by an `|` statement, and it goes over one of the row and only one condition is true then is going to throw an error when it tries to resolve the addition of statement since not all the variable names of the statement are found in that row.

Comment: @Zesima29 I got your point. Added completely different approach.

Comment: What about my solution? What is timings?

Comment: @jezrael `339 ms ± 3.41 ms per loop`. You win!!